# Selenium webdriver Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using NodeJS selenium within my electron desktop application.

```
"electron-chromedriver": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
```

I followed [electron documentation about using selenium](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver#3-connect-to-chromedriver) inside electron app and I have code like this:

```
let chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
let chromeOptions = { 'args': ['--disable-infobars'] };
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
capabilities.setPageLoadStrategy('eager');

this.driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)
    .usingServer('http://localhost:9515')
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
```

after above code there is chain of promises which are doing many different things.

Except that I'm runing `chromedriver` command in terminal within `./node_modules/.bin/` directory.

> Starting ChromeDriver 69.0.3497.106 (857b284701ddf7bef0f14fa76416cf7ca786b411) on port 9515
>   Only local connections are allowed.

Now when I run entire code it sometimes works correctly but occasionally it print error in terminal in which I `npm run dev` electron app:

> Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515

I read several similiar SO questions but none of them was helpful. I don't really understand how it's possible that some piece of code is sometimes working and sometimes causing error.

I also checked ports `9515` (chromedriver) and `9080` (electron nodeJS) after getting error and everything looks fine:

[image: alt]

---

I've done some more debugging and I found out that **probably** this:

```
webElement.getAttribute('style')
```

is **sometimes** causing my error. When I delete above (and also `.then()` and `.catch` after it ofcourse) error stop occuring. However I don't know how geting inline styles of webElement might be relevant to *connection refused* error.

Comment: Where is your server hosted?

Comment: I'm runing code locally. I've created my electron app using electron-vue cli boilerplate. `npm run dev` which I call from terminal is runing script `"dev": "node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",` which open local server. The file is: https://gist.github.com/BorysTyminski/0dd37249b274c12796b030b565671564

Comment: whats the output of command - "lsof -i :9515" when the connection is refused?

Comment: Well I can't really run any command until I stop server with ctrl+C. Except that I'm using windows10. I don't know if command `lsof` is recognized command in windows.

Comment: My bad. Poweshell and cmd are both available to run commands. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows for seeing whats running on your port

Comment: No matter if i run command before or after connection refused the outup is: https://i.imgur.com/01qEZ8V.png

Comment: The above screenshot must be when your server is running perfectly, server is  running on the port 9515. Whats the output when server doesn't work.

Comment: Chromedriver is running on the port 9515. Node side of electron is running on `server.listen(9080)` as you can see in file which I post gist above in comment. Anyway I'm not lying, I execute command after the error occur. Take a look: https://i.imgur.com/pcfx1MI.png

Comment: Running that stuff in your personal user folder may cause some problems with antivirus/host intrusion software. Also, anonymous access to your users folder isn’t a great idea. Might not be your issue for this, but moving that kind of stuff outside of your users folder is just some general feedback.

Comment: No anonymous user should be allowed to write to your user folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used the following capability:

```
capabilities.setPageLoadStrategy('eager');
```

Earlier, in a couple of QAs we have discussed about `PageLoadStrategy` as **`eager`** for *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome*:

- [Page load strategy for Chrome driver (Updated till Selenium v3.12.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver-updated-till-selenium-v3-12-0/43737358#43737358)
- [“Eager” Page Load Strategy workaround for Chromedriver Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087832/eager-page-load-strategy-workaround-for-chromedriver-selenium-in-python)

The conclusion was, as per [WebDriver Status](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/chromedriver_status.md) you will find the list of all **WebDriver commands** and their current support in **ChromeDriver** based on what is in the [**WebDriver Specification**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/). Once the implementation are **completed** from all aspects **PageLoadStrategy.EAGER** is bound to be functionally present within *Chrome Driver*.

Similar discussions were also active on several threads within `bugs.chromium.org` and `groups.google.com` as follows:

- [PageLoadStrategy.EAGER doesn't work with chromedriver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/TvN2vhyskNg)
- [Support eager page load strategy](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1902)
- [Implement page load timeout API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=9#c29)

If you look at [page_load_strategy.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/page_load_strategy.cc) `PageLoadStrategy` as **`eager`** is yet to be implemented:

```
#include "chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/page_load_strategy.h"
#include "base/logging.h"
#include "chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/navigation_tracker.h"
#include "chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/non_blocking_navigation_tracker.h"
const char PageLoadStrategy::kNormal[] = "normal";
const char PageLoadStrategy::kNone[] = "none";
const char PageLoadStrategy::kEager[] = "eager";
PageLoadStrategy* PageLoadStrategy::Create(
    std::string strategy,
    DevToolsClient* client,
    const BrowserInfo* browser_info,
    const JavaScriptDialogManager* dialog_manager) {
  if (strategy == kNone) {
    return new NonBlockingNavigationTracker();
  } else if (strategy == kNormal) {
    return new NavigationTracker(client, browser_info, dialog_manager);
  } else {
    NOTREACHED() << "invalid strategy '" << strategy << "'";
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

This may be root cause of the `Error: ECONNREFUSED` which you are seeing as the *dummy elements/iframes* may not have generated/created/rendered completely as per the *Chrome Browser* startup logs:

```
[1517231304.270][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=11) {
   "expression": "var isLoaded = document.readyState == 'complete' ||    document.readyState == 'interactive';if (isLoaded) {  var frame = document.createElement('iframe');  frame.name = 'chromedriver dummy frame'; ..."
}
```

This issue inturn causes the line:

```
webElement.getAttribute('style')
```

to cause the actual error.

---

### Solution

For a cleaner test you may need to use `PageLoadStrategy` as **`normal`** instead as:

```
capabilities.setPageLoadStrategy('normal');
```

---

### Outro

Some relevant discussions:

- [How to fix python-selenium error “connection refused” when initializing a selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474999/how-to-fix-python-selenium-error-connection-refused-when-initializing-a-seleni)
- [How to fix “WebDriverException: Message: connection refused”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920639/how-to-fix-webdriverexception-message-connection-refused)
- [ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer and ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on heroku with mobile testing through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349410/connectionreseterror-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer-and-err-name-not-reso)

Comment: I don't know who -1 but this answer is correct. Eager is sometimes causing error. Anyway I switch to puppeteer because selenium makes some things hard - like changing `window.navigator`. Also I feel like puppeteer is performing better.