# Connection Refused and Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource error with Selenium GeckoDriver and Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, splinter

As per the title, now, firefox opens up, seems to do nothing, then disappears!

1. I've run this before from a local ubuntu 16.04 VM and all was fine.

(Yes, i have upgraded to the latest of selenium etc. as follows:
selenium 3.141.0
splinter 0.10.0
six 1.12.0
urllib3 1.25.3)
Now, geckodriver.log shows the following:

```
1559646629845   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:60172  
1559646630836   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path /tmp/rust_mozprofile.5DqFww40mZ6W  
1559646630851   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox  
1559646630857   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:46681  
1559646631959   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons  
1559646631960   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/  
1559646631960   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*  
1559646637156   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 2828  
console.error: BroadcastService:  
  receivedBroadcastMessage: handler for  
  remote-settings/monitor_changes  
  threw error:  
  Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource..  
  Stack:  
    remoteSettingsFunction/remoteSettings.pollChanges@resource://services-settings/remote-settings.js:190:13  
JavaScript error: jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja!/components/nsUrlClassifierListManager.js, line 329: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIUrlClassifierDBService.getTables]  
JavaScript error: jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja!/components/nsUrlClassifierListManager.js, line 329: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIUrlClassifierDBService.getTables]  
1559646742440   Marionette      INFO    Stopped listening on port 2828ss
```

2. I've also tried this on a remote ubuntu-16.04 VM (without a GUI ), console shows the same "connection refused" message but this time, geckodriver.log shows a different issue, as follows:
   (selenium 3.141.0
   six 1.12.0
   splinter 0.10.0
   urllib3 1.25.3)

   ```
   1559563047915   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0  
   1559563047918   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:51758  
   1559563049045   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser  /usr/bin/firefox with args ["-marionette"]  
   MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol  
   Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory  
   Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported:   localhost:11.0  
   Error: cannot open display: localhost:11.0  
   1559644244502   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
   1559644244506   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:53086
   1559644245634   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
   MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
   Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
   Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: localhost:10.0
   Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
   ```

my test code is :

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit( 'https://www.google.com' )
browser.fill( 'q', 'splinter - python acceptance testing     for web application' )
browser.quit()
```

I appreciate there are similar questions posted to "connection refused" type issues with selenium...  I am hoping to find a solution specific to python  what seems to me as either a 'network issue' or a 'display issue'...

Comment: For 1: Maybe try without the profile and see if that makes a difference.  For 2:... no GUI seems like it could be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
1559646629845   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:60172  
1559646630836   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path /tmp/rust_mozprofile.5DqFww40mZ6W  
1559646630851   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox  
1559646630857   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:46681  
1559646631959   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons  
1559646637156   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 2828  
console.error: BroadcastService:  
  receivedBroadcastMessage: handler for  
  remote-settings/monitor_changes  
  threw error:  
  Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource..  
  Stack:  
    remoteSettingsFunction/remoteSettings.pollChanges@resource://services-settings/remote-settings.js:190:13  
JavaScript error: jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja!/components/nsUrlClassifierListManager.js, line 329: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsIUrlClassifierDBService.getTables]  
1559646742440   Marionette      INFO    Stopped listening on port 2828s
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *GeckoDriver* version **geckodriver v0.18.0**. (as per first line in second set of logs *...geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.18.0...*)
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.141.0**.
- Your *Firefox* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *GeckoDriver v0.18.0* *Selenium Client v3.141.0*.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to latest [GeckoDriver v0.24.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is present in the required location.
- *GeckoDriver* is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* to current *Firefox v65.0.2* levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

> **Note**: Always maintain the following [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility matrix](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

> You can find a relevant detailed discussionin [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)

---

### Outro

- [How to fix python-selenium error “connection refused” when initializing a selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474999/how-to-fix-python-selenium-error-connection-refused-when-initializing-a-seleni/52537137#52537137)
- [How to fix “WebDriverException: Message: connection refused”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920639/how-to-fix-webdriverexception-message-connection-refused/47921529#47921529)

Comment: This is brilliant ! I followed the steps in the solution. It now works like it used to. Bit of a rude shock when things just stop working when you need it to do its thing. I'll need to keep an eye on these tests. OK for now. @DebanjanB Dhonnobaad !